# Subtract Matrices row-wise in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

Is there any **built-in method** in OpenCV (**C++ API**) to **subtract two matrices row-wise**.

I have the following matrices:

```
Mat A(10,2, CV_64F);
Mat B(1,2, CV_64F);
Mat C(10,2, CV_64F);

C = A - B;

// B is a 1 x 2 matrix, A is a 10 x 2 matrix, and C is a 10 x 2 matrix.
```

**Each row in A has to be subtracted from B and stored as a row in C**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it the following way:

```
Mat A(10,2, CV_64F);
Mat B(1,2, CV_64F);
Mat C(0,2, CV_64F);
Mat D(0,2, CV_64F);

for(int i=0;i<A.rows;i++)
{
C=(A.row(i)-B.row(0));
D.push_back(C.row(0));
}

cout<<"A\n"<<A<<endl;
cout<<"B\n"<<B<<endl;
cout<<"C\n"<<C<<endl;
cout<<"D\n"<<D<<endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to OpenCV document, you can use the method subtract(). In your case, it is

```
subtract(A.row(0), B.row(0), tempMat);
```

Then push the tempMat to C, or CopyTo.

Here is the reference:
[OpenCV Array Operation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20subtract(InputArray%20src1,%20InputArray%20src2,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20mask,%20int%20dtype))

Answer (score 0):

Use `cv::repeat()` 
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#repeat

```
cv::Mat A = cv::Mat::ones(10, 2, CV_64F) * 5.0;
cv::Mat B = cv::Mat::ones(1, 2, CV_64F) * 3.0;
cv::Mat BRepeat = cv::repeat(B, A.rows, 1);
cv::Mat C = A - BRepeat;

cout << endl;
cout << "A" << endl << A << endl << endl;
cout << "B" << endl << B << endl << endl;
cout << "BRepeat" << endl << BRepeat << endl << endl;
cout << "C" << endl << C << endl << endl;
```